# How to group by in MATLAB on 2 columns

Tags: matlab, group-by, statistics, mean

I have data stored in table format as

```
data = table(['A';'B';'A';'A';'B'], datetime('now')-days([1;2;1;2;2]), rand(5,1)*100, 'VariableNames', {'Stock','Date','Open'})
```

Output of the above data is

```
   Stock            Date             Open 
   _____    ____________________    ______

    A        28-Aug-2020 07:51:36    81.472
    B        27-Aug-2020 07:51:36    90.579
    A        28-Aug-2020 07:51:36    12.699
    A        27-Aug-2020 07:51:36    91.338
    B        27-Aug-2020 07:51:36    63.236
```

I want to calculate the average of `Open` grouped by `Stock` and `Date`.
Desired output would be

```
 Stock            Date            GroupCount    mean_Open
 _____    ____________________    __________    _________
  A       27-Aug-2020 16:27:51        1          91.338  
  A       28-Aug-2020 16:27:51        2          47.086  
  B       27-Aug-2020 16:27:51        2          76.908
```

What I've tried:

**First Attempt**

```
mu = varfun(@mean, data,'GroupingVariables',{'Stock', 'Date'},'InputVariables','Open')
```

Error from above code:

```
Error using tabular/varfun (line 206)
Not enough input arguments.
```

If grouped on single variable I am able to get results for example below code works:

```
mu = varfun(@mean, data,'GroupingVariables','Stock','InputVariables','Open')
```

Output:

```
Stock    GroupCount    mean_Open
_____    __________    _________

A        3             61.836   
B        2             76.908
```

Output from

```
which mean -all

C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\mean.m
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017b\toolbox\matlab\bigdata\@tall\mean.m              % tall method
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017b\toolbox\matlab\timefun\@duration\mean.m          % duration method
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017b\toolbox\matlab\timefun\@datetime\mean.m          % datetime method
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017b\toolbox\distcomp\parallel\@codistributed\mean.m  % codistributed method
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017b\toolbox\distcomp\gpu\@gpuArray\mean.m            % gpuArray method
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017b\toolbox\finance\ftseries\@fints\mean.m           % fints method
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017b\toolbox\mbc\mbctools\@sweepset\mean.m            % sweepset method
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017b\toolbox\stats\stats\@ProbDistUnivParam\mean.m    % ProbDistUnivParam method
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017b\toolbox\matlab\timeseries\@timeseries\mean.m     % timeseries method
```

Output from:

```
which('mean','in','varfun')

C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\mean.m
```

**Second Attempt**

```
[G,tabout] = findgroups(data(:,{'Stock','Date'}));
tabout.avgOpen = splitapply(@mean,data.Open,G);
```

error from above piece of code:

```
Error using findgroups (line 86)
Unable to use a character array as a grouping variable.  First convert the character array to a cell array of character vectors using cellstr. Then specify the cell array as
a grouping variable.
```

Comment: Could you clarify what the desired output is? It seems incomplete

Comment: @Paolo I've added the desired outcome along with values.

Comment: Cool. Those dates don't look right though?

Comment: Would probably be simpler to provide a reproduction example with fixed data instead of random

Comment: @Paolo I am least concerned with dates however I 've fixed that. The numbers are generated randomly.  If you can provide a solution using any Dates or any Prices or Any category that would suffice and I don't have a problem with that. The problem here is that the code is not working. If you can let me know how to make it work irrespective of the data I won't mind accepting that answer. But the concept of grouping on 2 columns should be covered in the answer.

Comment: I get correct output without any error from the code under your "first attempt". (R2018a). i.e. `mu=varfun(@mean, data,'GroupingVariables',{'Stock','Date'},'InputVariables','Open')` gives: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMRq0.png

Comment: @SardarUsama all I can say is that I don't have R2018a. If I did I would've used group_summary() instead